# HTML in Sweet Alert

Tags: javascript, jquery, sweetalert

This has been answered several times but it seems Sweet Alert has made changes and html:true no longer works, just trying to add a clickable URL

Docs say 
HTML is no longer used. Instead, use the content object.
but they don't really provide any examples

Below code works but displays the entire `<a href .... </a>` rather than just the CLICK HERE

```
swal({
  title: "TITLE HERE",
  //text: "<a href='#'>CLICK HERE<a>",
  html: true
});
```

Comment: There is examples: `html: $('<div>').html('<a href="#">CLICK HERE<a>')`

Comment: Try putting the content into the `html` property instead of the `text` property. Looks like you can use a jQuery object, as well. https://limonte.github.io/sweetalert2/

Comment: again html has been removed from Sweet Alert, search for HTML on https://sweetalert.js.org/guides/   -- can you please post a example?

Comment: @user3228114 you can try with `content ` and pass a custom dom element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code should work . You can use `content` now with specific DOM element

```
var el = document.createElement("a");
el.href = "www.stackoverflow.com";
el.innerText = "Click here";
swal("Write something here:", {
  content: el,
});
```

check this here : 
https://sweetalert.js.org/docs/#content

as shown in the sample you can pass a slider input to the alert

Here is a working fiddle 
https://jsfiddle.net/vq13hac4/2/

Comment: ahhh thanks Niladri that was the help I needed -- works! thanks

Comment: @user3228114 please mark this answer if it works for you . Thanks and welcome.

Answer (score 4):

Sweet Alert can handle the creation of the html element for you. So the answer by Niladri can be rewritten as:

```
swal("Write something here:", {
    content: {
        element: "a",
        attributes: {
            href: "http://www.stackoverflow.com",
            innerText: "Click here"}}});
```

Answer (score 1):

@Niladri options is good for Sweet Alert 2.

```
      var form = document.createElement("div");
      form.innerHTML = `
      <span id="tfHours">0</span> hours<br>
      <input style="width:90%;" type="range" name="tfHours" value=0 step=1 min=0 max=25
      onchange="window.changeHours(this.value)"
      oninput="window.changeHours(this.value)"
      ><br>
      <span id="tfMinutes">0</span> min<br>
      <input style="width:60%;" type="range" name="tfMinutes" value=0 step=5 min=0 max=60
      onchange="window.changeMinutes(this.value)"
      oninput="window.changeMinutes(this.value)"
      >`;

      swal({
        title: 'Request time to XXX',
        text: 'Select time to send / request',
        content: form,
        buttons: {
          cancel: "Cancel",
          catch: {
            text: "Create",
            value: 5,
          },
        }
      }).then((value) => {
        //console.log(slider.value);
      });
```

I have created a Codepen with a Sweet Alert form data inside. [Try it here!](https://codepen.io/gtamborero/pen/abdOxPQ)